# Syncing photos doesn't appear to do anything

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone, photos

I have a ton of photos on my iPhone (4S, although most were taken with my previous 3G). I am trying to sync them to my computer (Windows Vista) but they are not appearing there.

I went to my iPhone in iTunes, clicked the "Photos" tab at the top and selected a folder. After synching, that folder now has a subfolder "iPod Photo Cache" with one file "Photo Database" that is 892 bytes.

Where are the photos? Do I need to do something different to actually copy the photos to this folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "photos" tab in iTunes is for syncing photos on your computer *to* your iPhone. To download the photos off your iPhone, use some software that downloads photos off cameras, such as [Windows Photo Gallery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Photo_Gallery).

Comment: Oh, well I saw I can just copy the files straight from Windows Explorer. Why is it called "sync" if the two folders are not actually synchronised?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat That I don't know. On Macs the "sync" tab syncs stuff over from iPhoto, maybe there isn't really a supported equivalent in the Windows world